# How to get the Scrollbar work during the multiple-entry (with condition) in tkinter frame within the tab?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar, frame, tkinter-entry

I was trying to create the scrolled-abled in the frame, where there will be multiple entry lines according to the number of items present. My questions are
1.) My frame `Nofy_frame1` with scrollbar is not working (Mentioned the comment `#NOT WORKING` part) and its position is too close to the entries I did not get any error response. How to solve it?
2.) How to stop/restart the loop while shifting the radio buttons of `method 1` and `method 2`? Since for each click on `Add entry` button for `method 2`, the result would be :

```
Price 1 :
Price 2 :
Price 3 :
Price 4 :
Price 5 :
```

and then next click on the same `Add entry` button I am getting

```
Price 6 :
Price 7 :
Price 8 :
Price 9 :
Price 10 :
```

instead of the above result
How to resolve it?

I have written the fair code below, Please let me know and clarify my mistakes

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkcalendar import Calendar,DateEntry
from tkinter import messagebox
from tkinter.scrolledtext import ScrolledText
import os
from tkinter import *
import numpy as ny

master0 = tk.Tk()

master0.config(background = "white") 
master0.title("Shop Cashier")
master0.geometry("1000x600")
master0.colour_schemes = [{"bg": "#eef1f5", "fg": "black"}, {"bg": "blue", "fg": "white"}]
tabs = ttk.Notebook(master0) 

C_1 = 'black'
C_2 = 'white'

TStyler = ttk.Style()
TStyler.configure("TFrame", background=C_2, foreground=C_1, borderwidth=0)

tab1 = ttk.Frame(tabs, style = "TFrame") 
tab2 = ttk.Frame(tabs, style = "TFrame")
tab3 = ttk.Frame(tabs, style = "TFrame")
C1 = Canvas(tab1, borderwidth=1, background="white")
C2 = Canvas(tab2, borderwidth=1, background="white")
C2 = Canvas(tab3, borderwidth=1, background="white")



tabs.add(tab1, text ='1')
tabs.add(tab2, text ='2') 
tabs.add(tab3, text ='3') 

tabs.pack(expand = 1, fill ="both") 
#-TAB1
quit_button = tk.Button(tab1, text="Finish", fg="White", bg = "#53c653",padx=10, pady=3,command=master0.destroy)
quit_button.place(x = 450, y= 430)

#-TAB2

InitialInv_r = tk.DoubleVar()
CF_result = tk.DoubleVar()
P_r = tk.DoubleVar()
iiit_r = tk.IntVar()
 
alent = []
FCI_list = []
VCI_list = []



def addEntry():
    if CF_result.get() == 2:
        Nofy_frame = Frame(tab2, width = 10, height = 200, bd = 0, background = "#fff080")
        Nofy_frame.place(x = 50, y= 150)
        Nofy_frame1 = Frame(tab2, width = 270, height = 400, bd = 0, background = "#fff080")
        Nofy_frame1.place(x = 50, y= 150)
        #============================================================NOT WORKING 
        Nofy_frame1.pack_propagate(0)  # stops frame from shrinking
        scroll = Scrollbar(Nofy_frame1)
        scroll.pack(side = RIGHT, fill = Y)
        #============================================================NOT WORKING
        for number in range(iiit_r.get()):
            number = len(alent)
            #label
            ylab = Label(Nofy_frame1, text="Price "+str(number+1)+" :",bg = "#fff080")
            ylab.grid(row=number+1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
            #Entry
            ent = Entry(Nofy_frame1, font=('calibri', 11), width = 33)
            ent.grid(row=number+1, column=2,padx=10, pady=20)
            alent.append( ent )
    elif CF_result.get() == 0:
        Nofy_frame = Frame(tab2, width = 328, height = 400, bd = 0, background = "#fff080")
        Nofy_frame.place(x = 50, y= 150)
        Nofy_frame2 = Frame(tab2, width = 270, height = 400, bd = 0, background = "#fff080")
        Nofy_frame2.place(x = 50, y= 150)
        ylab1 = Label(Nofy_frame2, text="Fixed Price :",bg = "#fff080" )
        ylab1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=2, pady=10)
        #Entry
        ent = Entry(Nofy_frame2, font=('calibri', 11), width = 30)
        ent.grid(row=1, column=2,padx=10, pady=20)
        alent.append( ent )
            
            
Disct = Label(tab2, text = '      Percentage', bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri", 12)) 
Disct.place(x=400, y=50)
Disctp = Label(tab2, text = '%', bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri", 12)) 
Disctp.place(x=642, y=50)
#Disct_frame = Frame(tab2, width = 200, height = 25, bd = 0, background = "white", highlightcolor = "black", highlightthickness = 1)
#Disct_frame.place(x = 530, y= 50)
Disctv = Entry(tab2,font=('calibri', 12), textvariable= P_r,width = 10, bd=1, bg='#fffce6', justify='left')
Disctv.place(x=560, y=50)

Nofy = Label(tab2, text = 'No. of items :', bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri", 12)) 
Nofy.place(x=700, y=50)
Nofy_frame = Frame(tab2, width = 328, height = 400, bd = 0, background = "#fff080", highlightcolor = "#fff080", highlightthickness = 1)
Nofy_frame.place(x = 50, y= 150)
Nofyv = Entry(tab2,font=('calibri', 12), textvariable= iiit_r, width = 5, bd=1, bg='#fffce6', justify='left')
Nofyv.place(x=800, y=50)

CashFlow = Label(tab2, text = 'Method', bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri light", 18)) 
CashFlow.place(x=50, y=100)

FCF_r = Radiobutton(tab2, variable = CF_result, value = 0, bg = "white")
FCF_r.place(x=180, y=110)
FCF_rr = Label(tab2, text = "method 1", bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri light", 12))
FCF_rr.place(x=200, y=108)

vCF_r = Radiobutton(tab2, variable = CF_result, value = 2,bg = "white")
vCF_r.place(x=380, y=110)
vCF_rr = Label(tab2, text = "method 2", bg = "white",padx=3, pady=1,font = ("calibri light", 12))
vCF_rr.place(x=400, y=108)


addEnt = Button(tab2, text='Add entry', fg="White", bg = "#1a1700", command=addEntry)
addEnt.place(x = 400, y= 150)


quit_button = tk.Button(tab2, text="Finish", fg="White", bg = "#53c653",padx=10, pady=3,command=master0.destroy)
quit_button.place(x = 900, y= 530)


master0.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please only ask about one problem at a time.

Comment: Sure i will explain, 1. How to restart the loop of the function? and I am sorry. @BryanOakley I will edit the question